# Cropping UIImage to custom path and keeping correct resolution?

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, core-animation

[image]

I have a view (blue background...) which I'll call "main" here, on main I added a `UIImageView` that I then rotate, pan and scale. On main I have a another subview that shows the cropping area. Anything out of that under the darker area needs to be cropped.

I am trying to figure out how to properly create a cropped image from this state. I want the resulting image to look like this:

[image]

I want to make sure to keep the resolution of the image.

Any idea?

I have tried to figure out how to use the layer.mask property of the UIImageView. After some feedback, I think I could have another view (B) on the blue view, on B I would then add the image view, so then I would make sure that B's frame would match the rect of the cropping mask overlay. I think that could work? The only thing is I want to make sure I don't lose resolution.

So, earlier I tried this:

```
maskShape.frame = imageView.bounds
maskShape.path = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 200)).cgPath
imageView.layer.mask = maskShape
```

The rect was just a test rect and the image would be cropped to that path, but, I wasn't sure how to get a UIImage from all this that could keep the large resolution of the original image

So, I have implemented the method suggested by marco, it all works with the exception of keeping the resolution.

I use this call to take a screenshot of the view the contains the image and I have it clip to bounds:

```
public func renderToImage(afterScreenUpdates: Bool = false) -> UIImage {
    let rendererFormat = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat.default()
    rendererFormat.opaque = isOpaque
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: bounds.size, format: rendererFormat)

    let snapshotImage = renderer.image { _ in
        drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: afterScreenUpdates)
    }
    return snapshotImage
}
```

The image I get is correct, but is not as sharp as the one I crop.

Hoe can I keep the resolution high?

Comment: To help us give you a simple answer update your question with: 1: What have you tried  2: What are your results 3: What are the problems from the results you get. Maybe a screenshot image to that.

Answer (score 0):

In your view which keeps the image you must set `clipsToBounds` to `true`. Not sure if I got well but I suppose it's your "cropping area"

Comment: the view that keeps the image is the blue view, which is full screen. Then it it there is the UIImageView that has the image... So, I am not sure what you mean. I need to be able to get a cropper UIImageView keeping resolution and that looks like what I posted...

Comment: @zumzum if I understood well you have a cropping area which is a view, don't you? So I think you have the image view inside that cropping area. Is it right? Then you can apply the clips to that cropping area. If it's not your view hierarchy you should move your image view inside a view which is your cropping area (so between the two black views) and in that view you apply the clips

Comment: ok, so, I see what you mean, I think it makes sense. Then I could just ask the view that contains the image view to render in a context. Would that keep the resolution of the image? In other words, I do't want to loose resolution...

Comment: with `clipsToBounds` the system crops everything which go outside your view bounds so you don't lose resolution, just you have a crop of the content outside of the view bounds